# Visualforce: How do I print the Current Date?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

How do I print the current date on Visualforce?

Stuff like Today(), System.now, doesn't work.

Haven't been able to find any documentation or stackoverflow questions regarding this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller, create a property:

```
public Date Today { get { return Date.today(); }}
```

In the VF page, try using:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date}">
    <apex:param value="{!Today}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Details on formatting the date can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 16):

Visualforce has Data and Time functions too, you can use {!NOW()} or {!TODAY()}.

For more details go [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)

Comment: I think this answer is by far the best.